Understanding why $f(\Omega)$ is closed
I am currently learning about characteristic classes in principal bundles from Kobayashi and Nomizu.
Following the notations used in the book, let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Take $f:\mathfrak{g}^k = \mathfrak{g} \times \cdots \times \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a multilinear, symmetric and $G$-invariant map. On the other hand, let $\Omega$ be the curvature form of a principal $G$-bundle $P\rightarrow M$, which has been endowed with an Ehresmann connection $\omega$. Finally, let $D$ be the covariant derivative on forms on $P$.
Define
$$
f(\Omega)(X_1, \cdots, X_{2k}) = \frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2k}} f(\Omega(X_{\sigma(1)}, X_{\sigma(2)}),\cdots, \Omega(X_{\sigma(2k-1)},X_{\sigma(2k)})) 
$$
Where the $X_i$ are vector fields over $P$. Thus $f(\Omega)$ is a 2k-form on $P$.
The authors now state the following,
'Since $D$ acts as a skew-derivation on the algebra of tensorial forms of $P$ and since $D\Omega$ = 0, it follows that $D(f(\Omega))=0$'.
While I do understand that D acts as a skew-derivation and I see where $D\Omega$ comes from, I am not seeing quite so easily how this implies that $D(f(\Omega))=0$. Basically, since $f(\Omega)$ isn't written in terms of wedge products I don't see how to use the skew-derivation condition.

Of course it's written in terms of wedge products, but because we're wedging $2$-forms together, the product is commutative. You can do the computation more explicitly by calculating the exterior derivative (rather than covariant derivative on the bundle) on the manifold and invoking the Bianchi identity in the form $d\Omega = \pm [\omega,\Omega]$.
